# Number of items missed while taking n random items m times out of n*m total items?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a list `'A'` of 100000 total items, no duplicates.

I then pick 50 items at a time 2000 times, putting them back every time (cloning them).

These 50*2000=100000 items I just picked(cloned) I use to try to build a new list `'B'`.

How many items form `'A'` will be missing in `'B'`?

How many of the items in `'B'` will be duplicates?

Comment: If you are picking the numbers randomly then you can not answer to your questions deterministically, instead you should try to find some probability distribution ot the outcomes of the experiment.

Comment: @JosuEtxezarretaMartinez I understand that but I still have no idea of how I should tackle the problem

Comment: Look at the answer given below, it gives you the probability of an item to be found out exactly $k$ times in $B$. Then you can find the expectation of such event to happen.

Comment: Here's how I would approach the problem.  Consider the Markov process where a new sample of $50$ is chosen and replaced, and this is repeated $2000$ times.  So the first time you are guaranteed to get $50$ different items, and subsequently the chances of getting items not picked before is dependent on how many of the total $10000$ items were chosen previously.  Making an effort of some kind to solve the problem yourself will give you a better appreciation of the work that succeeds in solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of a fixed item to be found  exactly $k$ times in $B$ is: $$p_k=\binom{2000}k\left(\frac{50}{100000}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{100000-50}{100000}\right)^{2000-k}$$

Then with linearity of expectation we find that $100000p_k$  items are expected to be found exactly $k$ times in list $B$.

So $100000p_0$ are expected to be missing and $100000(1-p_0-p_1)$ are expected to be found more than once.